# IDE for Python + Django Template Highlight + JQuery

Tags: jquery, python, django-templates

I try Netbeans 6.7 for python but don't have a good django template highlight and jquery code completion... i did find a project in google for django for netbeans but they don't explain how to do...

Also I try eclipse with pydev, but have some problems with code competion on my class...

I like to much Netbeans 6.7... I need more of javascript code completion!!! template highlight is just for help my webdesigner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana is great in HTML/CSS/Javascript editing.

You may also refer to this question:

[Which text editor has the most useful autocomplete for web page editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470/which-text-editor-has-the-most-useful-autocomplete-for-web-page-editing)